# LibEtPan / iOS: Symbol(s) not found …

Tags: ios, xcode, undefined-symbol

I tried to use LibEtPan as a backend for a mail client. I downloaded the source code from https://github.com/dinhviethoa/libetpan and additional libs from https://github.com/bindle/iOSPorts too. I ran the LibEtPan build-mac/update.sh and added the libetpan.xcodeproj to my project as well as openldap.xcodeproj, openssl.xcodeproj, Cyrus SASL.xcodeproj.

I set the following Target Dependencies: `libetpan ios (libetpan), lber (openldap), ldap (openldap), crypto (openssl), ssl (openssl), sasl2 (Cyrus SASL) and I Linked Binary With Libraries: libetpan-ios.a, libiconv.dylib, liblber.a, libldap.a, libcrypto.a, libsasl2, libssl.a`

But as soon as I call something like mailimap_new i get the error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_mailimap_extension_xgmmsgid", referenced from:
      _internal_extension_list in libetpan-ios.a(mailimap_extension.o)
```

(same with armv7 or other architectures)

I have no idea which lib i have to include additionally.